# sessions in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, session

Im building an login with angularjs and PHP. The problem I have is that the session not seem to have been set.

I have this controller that uses a service when I hit the login button:

Controller:

```
$scope.doLogin = function() {
loginService.login({username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password});
```

};

Here is my services:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('gameApp_services').factory('sessionService', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        set:function(key, value) {
            return sessionStorage.setItem(key,value);
        },
        get:function(key) {
            return sessionStorage.getItem(key);
        },
        destroy:function(key) {
            $http.post('lib/destroy_session.php'); //Förstör sessionen
            return sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
        }
    };
}]).factory('loginService', function($http,$location,sessionService) {
    return {
        login: function(data, scope) {
            var $promise = $http.post("lib/action.php", data); //send data to action.php
            $promise.then(function(msg) {
                var uid = msg.data;
                console.log(uid);
                if(uid) {
                    //scope.msgtxt='Correct information';
                    sessionService.set('sess_id', uid);
                    $location.path('/game');
                } else {
                    scope.msgtxt='Incorrect information';
                    $location.path('/firstpage');
                }
            });
        },
        logout:function() {
            sessionService.destroy('sess_id');
            $location.path('/firstpage');
        },
        islogged:function() {

            var $checkSessionServer = $http.post('lib/check_session.php');
            return $checkSessionServer;

            /*if(sessionService.get('user')) {
                return true;
            }*/
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see, I'm making a call to my backend, where I check the username and password, and set's the session. The uid that is returned, contains the sessionID=1:

```
public function DoLogin($username, $password)
    {
        //Kolla så att användarnamn och lösenord är korrekt, returnera true eller false
        $get_user = "SELECT id, username,password FROM users WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'";
        $user_result = mysql_query($get_user)
                        or die(mysql_error());


        if(mysql_num_rows($user_result) == 1)
        {
            $_SESSION['sess_id'] = mysql_result($user_result, 0);
            $_SESSION['sess_user'] = $username;
            return $_SESSION['sess_id'];
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

This works, the correct data is returned back as expected, thus, the session id 1.

In my app.js I have code that prevents you from going to the /game page by typing it in the URL:

```
gameApp.run(function($rootScope, $location, loginService) {
    var routespermission=['/game']; //route that require login
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
        if(routespermission.indexOf($location.path()) !=-1)
        {
            var connected = loginService.islogged();
            connected.then(function(msg) {
                console.log(msg);
                if(!msg.data) {
                    $location.path('/');
                }                   
            }); 
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see, Im using my loginService here, where I'm refering to islooged in the service. In islogged I make a call to my PHP backend, check_session.php, where I check if the session exists:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['sess_id'])) {
    echo "authentified";
}
?>
```

This returns an empty string, the session is not set. When I try var_dump($_SESSION), the result is NULL.

How can this be possible, when I set the session in my backend when I log in, and the resulting value is 1?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to operate session with angular?

Session is store at browser and server,when you start a request by angular,session will be carried by request header automatically, and you can verify it with you php function at backend, so I think you should check your php code to confirm if session store is avaliable or your broswer can store session by cookies or session store

Comment: As you can see in my question,  I'm verifying it with php, in check_session.php..

Comment: Set a session and get it from another request to see if session is exist?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry I`m not a php developer,but with my experience,angular `get/post` a request,session will automatically add in request `Header`,so if you can`t get session from a http request, maybe you set session fail ever before

Comment: The session is created When I hit the login button, beacause return $_SESSION['sess_id'] is 1, which Is correct. It is in check_session.php that the problem is, $_SESSION['sess_id'] don't seem to be set here?

Comment: If you don`t change this session, you can get it from another request,think you can visit other pages and get session to see if session presnet